# Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=55.0.2, platform=WINDOWS}]

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have set up a selenium grid hub and node. In my java I set my capabilities like this:

```
Login.capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
Login.capability.setVersion("55.0.2");
Login.capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
Login.capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
Login.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/wd/hub"), Login.capability);
```

When I start the build I get this error message:

```
Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=55.0.2, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

The hub output:

```
selenium grid no capabilities found in request
```

The node output says this:

```
16:23:13.323 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "goog:chromeOptions": {
  },
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "version": "55.0.2"
}
16:23:13.324 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5) on port XXXXXXXXX
Only local connections are allowed.
```

So it seems the node works correctly but why does the hub say that there are no capabilities in the log?

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, version=55.0.2, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

As per your code trials you have set the *Chrome Browser* version to **55.0.2**. Hence you need to ensure that the *Selenium Node* client have **Chrome Browser v55.0.2** installed in it.

From another perspective:

- You are using **ChromeDriver 2.42**
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver 2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v55.0.2*

### Solution

As a solution you need to:

- Keep *JDK* upgraded to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Keep *Selenium* upgraded to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))